# How to mask UITableViewCells underneath a UITableView Transparent Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want the header to mask the cells, but not the background.

I have a UITableView with transparent headers and cells similar to Apple's Notification Center (when you swipe down on the status bar on your iPhone).  I can't figure out how to mask the cells so they don't show up underneath the header when it scrolls.

I've tried changing the contentInsets of the tableview, and I've tried changing the frame of the header View to a negative origin.

Comment: Are you talking about table headers, or section headers?

Comment: @RonLugge He's talking about section headers. You can clearly see what he means when you open the notification center as he described.

Comment: I wonder if that is a transparent header (in Notification Center), or just one that has the same background as the rest of the screen? Could you solve your problem by doing that, or is your background to complicated for that to work?

Comment: @rdelmar The header in the Notification Center is transparent when it moves, and I'm guessing it doesn't change depending on position. My TableView style is pretty similar to the Apple Notification Center, it has a complex background and multiple sections that rely on shadows and highlights to add depth.  Downgrading the graphics to an opaque header would be my last resort.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try to make a subclass of `UITableviewCell` and add these methods

```
- (void)maskCellFromTop:(CGFloat)margin {
    self.layer.mask = [self visibilityMaskWithLocation:margin/self.frame.size.height];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (CAGradientLayer *)visibilityMaskWithLocation:(CGFloat)location {
    CAGradientLayer *mask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    mask.frame = self.bounds;
    mask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    mask.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location], nil];
    return mask;
}
```

and add this delegate method in `UITableView`

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (iNotifyTableViewCell *cell in self.visibleCells) {
        CGFloat hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + [iNotifyHeaderView height] - cell.frame.origin.y;
        if (hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= cell.frame.size.height) {
            [cell maskCellFromTop:hiddenFrameHeight];
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that `[iNotifyHeaderView height]` is the height of the `HeaderView`. and use `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` for the custom cell.

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm! I was struggling with this all day. I can't believe I had to link the QuartzCore.framework just for this. However I want to replicate your code for footers too but I can't get how does the mask work, can you explain a little?

Comment: in iOS mask is kinda different, White portion shows the part and transparent doesn't. So this code makes a mask transparent at the top with the same height as header but rest is white, so the cell portion is visible, but the part behind the header is hidden. :)

Comment: Oh ok, however at the end I didn't use it because it made some glitches when device was rotated and the data was reloaded.

Comment: Can ANY of you guys tell me what to do with the scrollview delegate? what is iNotifyTableViewCell? And where is self.visibleCells pointing to? this is what i have so far in my class, I have explicitly created a UITableView programmatically setting the delegates myself etc. Data is being displayed well but need to fade the cells as it goes under the transparent header. I have subclassed a UItableViewCell & called it maskedCell : UITableViewCell and added the two methods in, but how and where do i add the third scrollview delegate methods so that my tableview can react to self.visible cells?

Comment: @Pavan 1) scrollview delegates will notify us that tableview is scrolling so hide the cells underneath. 2) iNotifyTableViewCell is the subclass which handles what fraction of the top cell should go underneath. 3) visibleCells is a property of UITableView, which returns current visible cells (not all).

Comment: @Pavan 4) UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView so will receive all scrollview delegate methods if you set a delegate.

Comment: Ok thanks for that but what of `[iNotifyHeaderView height]` how can you grab the height of a cell from a class was that segment meant to read `[cell height]` instead?

Comment: ^ Pavan, I normally discourage the use of "Magic Numbers" in code, but in your case, you should just be able to enter in a CGFloat value where it says `[iNotifyHeaderView height]` instead of pulling it. Though you can just go `[self.tableViewName heightForHeaderInSection:0]` if they are all the same.

Comment: @Pavan iNotifyHeaderView has a height method, it is unto you what you are returning with it. For the masking purpose I need the header height, default is UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: @AlexMarkman ahh it was a class method! As for everything else, thank you for taking your time in explaining the details of your code. I shall try again. I'm expecting my cells to gradually disappear as though a gradient had been apply to it when scrolling under the top header section whilst the header's background would still show the view's background. Hopefully it all works as expected! cant wait to implement it again. Will let you know if i have any further questions! thanks

Comment: @AlexMarkman thank you, works perfectly. I would add the top of the tableView's `contentInset` property to the `hiddenFrameHeight` you are calculating to account for the automatic inset that iOS 7 adds to scrollViews, and to any space added by refresh controls etc: `CGFloat hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + [iNotifyHeaderView height] - cell.frame.origin.y + scrollView.contentInset.top;`

Comment: Great solution, thank you! @boliva thank you for your comment about iOS 7, really helpful

Comment: I have also added this code to UITableViewCell's `maskCellFromTop:` method to increase performance (removing mask if margin is not appropriate for current cell)     
`if (margin > 0) {
        self.layer.mask = [self visibilityMaskWithLocation:margin/self.frame.size.height];
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
    else {
        self.layer.mask = nil;
    }`

Comment: I implemented this solution, but it crashes with "-[UITableViewCell maskCellFromTop:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". I did call the method on an instance of the subclass, not UITableViewCell....

Comment: Hello @AlexMarkman-  Can you suggest the same for footerview?

Comment: It is working fine with the fixed table view cell height, but the view is cropping for the dynamic cell height until scroll the table view. can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 18):

A little edit on Alex Markman's answer, where you could skip creating a subclass for an UITableViewCell. Benefit of this approach is that you can use it for multiple different UITableViewCells.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        CGFloat hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - cell.frame.origin.y;
        if (hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= cell.frame.size.height) {
            [self maskCell:cell fromTopWithMargin:hiddenFrameHeight];
        }
    }
}

- (void)maskCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell fromTopWithMargin:(CGFloat)margin
{
    cell.layer.mask = [self visibilityMaskForCell:cell withLocation:margin/cell.frame.size.height];
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (CAGradientLayer *)visibilityMaskForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withLocation:(CGFloat)location
{
    CAGradientLayer *mask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    mask.frame = cell.bounds;
    mask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    mask.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location], nil];
    return mask;
}
```

Comment: Love this. worked like a charm. I like that I didn't have to subclass anything.  I only had to modify self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height to use the height of my table header. -rrh

Comment: This is a good solution, but there is an issue. If you use some sort of paging in your table view when loading data, there is an issue with the mask, i.e. it hides the bottom part of the last cell when the tablefooterview which shows the loading indicator for the paging igets hidden.

Answer (score 12):

@Alex Markman - your answer is great and was very usefull for me, but I found that when you're scrolling on retina devices, the cells do not scroll smoothly. I found that it is caused by layer's `locations` parameter during the rendering process:

`mask.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location];`

I slightly modified your code. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
- (void)maskCellFromTop:(CGFloat)margin
{
    self.layer.mask = [self visibilityMaskFromLocation:margin];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (CAGradientLayer *)visibilityMaskFromLocation:(CGFloat)location
{
    CAGradientLayer *mask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(
                            self.bounds.origin.x,
                            location+self.bounds.origin.y,
                            self.bounds.size.width,
                            self.bounds.size.height-location);
    mask.colors = @[
                    (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] CGColor],
                    (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] CGColor]
                    ];
    return mask;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift version

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { 
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        let hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - cell.frame.origin.y
        if (hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= cell.frame.size.height) {
            maskCell(cell: cell, margin: Float(hiddenFrameHeight))
        }
    }
}

func maskCell(cell: UITableViewCell, margin: Float) {
    cell.layer.mask = visibilityMaskForCell(cell: cell, location: (margin / Float(cell.frame.size.height) ))
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func visibilityMaskForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, location: Float) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let mask = CAGradientLayer()
    mask.frame = cell.bounds
    mask.colors = [UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor, UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    mask.locations = [NSNumber(value: location), NSNumber(value: location)]
    return mask;
}
```

Comment: It works fine, yet I've different tableview at the bottom of the same ViewController and when I scroll the second tableview, the cells of the first tableview disappear too! what is the problem ?

Comment: On iOS 14 this is not working properly while rotating the device to vertical and back. It cuts all cells on the side. Seems like something with the coordinate system.

Comment: It is working fine with the fixed table view cell height, but the view is cropping for the dynamic cell height until scroll the table view. can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 5):

Clean Swift 3 Version:

```
extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            let hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - cell.frame.origin.y
            if (hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= cell.frame.size.height) {
                if let customCell = cell as? CustomCell {
                    customCell.maskCell(fromTop: hiddenFrameHeight)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    public func maskCell(fromTop margin: CGFloat) {
        layer.mask = visibilityMask(withLocation: margin / frame.size.height)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    private func visibilityMask(withLocation location: CGFloat) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let mask = CAGradientLayer()
        mask.frame = bounds
        mask.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        let num = location as NSNumber
        mask.locations = [num, num]
        return mask
    }
}
```

I just used this and it works like a charm. I want to thank everyone in the post! Up votes all around!

Comment: It works fine, yet I've different tableview at the bottom of the same ViewController and when I scroll the second tableview, the cells of the first tableview disappear too! what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible solutions, no code - just the idea:

1. not generic, should work with the settup/design apple uses at the Notification Center.

Make the Section-Header opaque, 'clone' the background-pattern of the table as background of the section-Header. Position the background-pattern depending on the section-header offset.

---

1. genereic, but probably more performance problems. Should work fine with few cells.

Add a Alpha Mask to all cell-layers. Move the Alpha Mask depending on the cell-position.

---

(use scrollViewDidScroll delegate method to maintain the background-pattern / Alpha-Mask offset).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the height of the section header to its minimum, and overriding UITableView's layoutSubviews to place the header on the tableView's superview, adjusting the frame's origin upward by its height.

Comment: Not the answer for the question being made.

Comment: The other answers were better. This post is an OP just being selfish with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 3 version didn't work for me because I added the UITableViewController as a subview. So I had to make some changes in the extension of the scrollview.

This should also work with UITableViewController that have been pushed from another ViewController (Note: not tested)

```
extension NavNotitionTableViewController {
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {

        let calculatedY = cell.frame.origin.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        if let customCell = cell as? NavNotitionTableViewCell {

            if(calculatedY < 44 && calculatedY > 0){
                let hideAmount = 44 - calculatedY;

                if let customCell = cell as? NavNotitionTableViewCell {
                    customCell.maskCell(fromTop: hideAmount)
                }
            }else if (calculatedY > 0){
                //All other cells
                customCell.maskCell(fromTop: 0)
            }else if (calculatedY < 0){
                customCell.maskCell(fromTop: cell.frame.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this example, I first get the frame Y origin of the cell and distract the scollViews contentOffsetY.

The height of my custom section is 44. So I define the hideAmount value for the mask.

The Cell functions are untouched:

```
public func maskCell(fromTop margin: CGFloat) {
    layer.mask = visibilityMask(withLocation: margin / frame.size.height)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}

private func visibilityMask(withLocation location: CGFloat) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let mask = CAGradientLayer()
    mask.frame = bounds
    mask.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    let num = location as NSNumber
    mask.locations = [num, num]
    return mask
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work if you wanted to show content behind your table view, but, since I'm only trying to create rounded headers with a plain solid colour background behind them, what solved it for me was mimicking transparency by setting the background colour of the header's background view to the background colour of the table view (or the first parent view with an opaque background).

Answer (score 0):

```swift
class YourViewController {
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            // if tableView is under navigationbar, set `systemTopInset`
            cell.sectionHeaderMask(delegate: self, systemTopInset: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
public extension UITableViewCell {
    func sectionHeaderMask<T: UITableViewDelegate>(delegate: T, systemTopInset: CGFloat = 0) {
        guard let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView else { return }
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self) else { return }
        guard let heightForHeader = delegate.tableView?(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: indexPath.section) else { return }
        let hiddenFrameHeight = tableView.contentOffset.y - self.frame.origin.y + heightForHeader + tableView.contentInset.top + systemTopInset
        if hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= self.frame.size.height {
            mask(margin: Float(hiddenFrameHeight))
        }
    }

    private func mask(margin: Float) {
        layer.mask = visibilityMask(location: (margin / Float(frame.size.height) ))
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    private func visibilityMask(location: Float) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let mask = CAGradientLayer()
        mask.frame = self.bounds
        mask.colors = [UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor, UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        mask.locations = [NSNumber(value: location), NSNumber(value: location)]
        return mask
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Or, if all you need is for your UI to look nice,
you could

### change your table view to not have floating section headers

In two quick and easy steps (iOS 6):

1. Change your UITableView style to UITableViewStyleGrouped. (You can do this from Storyboard/NIB, or via code.)
2. Next, set your tableview's background view to a empty view like so [in either a method such as  *viewDidAppear*  or even in the  *cellForRow*  method (though I would prefer the former)].

> ```
> yourTableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:listTableView.bounds];
> ```

Voila, now you have your table view - but without the floating section headers. Your section headers now scroll along with the cells and your messy UI problems are solved!

Do try this out and let me know how it goes. 
Happy coding :)

EDIT: for iOS 7, simply change the table view style to '*UITableViewStyleGrouped*' and change the view's tint color to 'clear color'.

Comment: While this answer «works» I don't think it addresses what the OP was asking. i think the idea was to keep the header visible but the cells underneath without a transparent header