# UITableView Header shows content behind it

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with headings on top of a textured background.  I want the header to stick at the top, which they do, but I don't want the cells to show behind it as they go by.  Here is an example:

[image: UITableView image]

New Content is the header.  You can see the rows of data under it as they scroll by.  I can't set the background of the header because it has to show the texture from the window behind it.  How can I not show the rows underneath the header?

Comment: We made the header background a solid color that blended into the background as much as possible.  Not ideal but there was nothing else to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't - not without making the headers opaque. The cells *are* what is behind the headers, so if you make the headers transparent, the cells are what you will see behind them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127138/how-to-mask-uitableviewcells-underneath-a-uitableview-transparent-header

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // bring first cell to front
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes u need to add `tableview.bringSubViewToFront(self.headerView)`

Comment: is the "V" in "view capitalized

Answer (score 0):

You can make the background image for the header the same texture as the UITableCell. You can also make the lower border have a drop shadow. The cells will appear to slip underneath the table headings.

Implement

`(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

and return a view with an `UIImageView` background. You will have to futz with this image a bit in photoshop to get the effect you're looking for.