# Mask all views below a UIView except background

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, calayer, mask

I have a transparent section header in a UITableView, which should let the cells scroll behind it but show the background image which is behind the tableview instead of the cells. I need a way to apply some sort of clipping mask to the section header which would make any views which go beneath it transparent, or something which shows the appropriate part of the background image as the header's background and follows when the header moves.

I have seen this [How to mask UITableViewCells underneath a UITableView Transparent Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127138/how-to-mask-uitableviewcells-underneath-a-uitableview-transparent-header), but it doesn't quite work as advertised, and is generally a bad implementation.

I have also tried this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.frame);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
}
```

in the section header's subclass, but this just shows the view with a black background.

If you need more explanation, here is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re79C.jpg

and here is what I want to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/11be2.jpg

Comment: Two things strike me about this question. The first one is that you probably have your view hierarchy all wrong. The second is that it sounds like you are trying to do some advanced drawing in UIKit where you should probably be using SpriteKit or something. I don't like your approach of trying to mask out other views in between to have the background show through. It's probably better to take the background image and put it behind your floating view again, possibly offsetting it using bounds. Research into the difference between manipulating frame and bounds.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained it better: the issue is with a transparent section header in a UITableView, which should let the cells scroll below it but show the background instead of the cells. I will add this info in the original question for clarification.

Comment: Ok, then I'd go with my suggestion: Take the background image again, apply it to the section header view and offset it using bounds.

Comment: Then it would need to constantly be moved, because the header view moves up when you scroll the table view. Do you have some sample code which could achieve this? Do you have any information about how this will affect performance? Otherwise, I would consider this a very valid answer to my question.

Comment: Yep, I get that. But it sure isn't more complicated than trying to apply a transparency mask to table view cells moving beneath. I would probably just not do this at all. Sorry can't provide any code examples. I have work of my own to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar task in a game. SpriteKit offers excellent performance on this since it has this as a built-in feature.

You can mix SpriteKit with UIKit but using SpriteKit as a background & not the other way around as you need, since SKView cannot have transparent background.

In my opinion you should here [create a custom header view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview?language=objc) or to [change the displaying of the cell](http://icodeswift.com/uitableview-willdisplayheaderview/).

Comment: I'm already using a custom header view, that's not the issue. Also, including SpriteKit just for this is not very good. If you need more info about the problem, see the gifs I have now attached to the original question.