# Is it possible to "hide" a UITableViewCell behind a transparent section header?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableview in my iOS project that uses an image as background. The image does not scroll, it is static. Because of that I also have transparent cells and section headers.
 Now my question is how can I make the (transparent) cells to "hide" or "disappear" behind the (also transparent) section header?
Is it possible?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Would you be okay with switching the tableview to a grouped tableview? So that the header scrolls up with the cells instead of them layering on top of each other? Because that would technically resolve this issue

Comment: Yeah but lets keep it a last resort :) Thanks for the answear though

Comment: This looks like it has some good ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127138/how-to-mask-uitableviewcells-underneath-a-uitableview-transparent-header?rq=1

Comment: You need to apply mask for all cells that located under header view. Use on scrollViewDidScroll

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your custom cell

```
public func maskCell(fromTop margin: CGFloat) {
    layer.mask = visibilityMask(withLocation: margin / frame.size.height)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}

private func visibilityMask(withLocation location: CGFloat) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let mask = CAGradientLayer()
    mask.frame = bounds
    mask.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    let num = location as NSNumber
    mask.locations = [num, num]
    return mask
}
```

and on you `ViewController UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     for cell in self.lessonsTableView.visibleCells {
         let paddingToDisapear = CGFloat(25)

         let hiddenFrameHeight = scrollView.contentOffset.y + paddingToDisapear - cell.frame.origin.y
         if (hiddenFrameHeight >= 0 || hiddenFrameHeight <= cell.frame.size.height) {
             if let customCell = cell as? LessonTableViewCell {
                 customCell.maskCell(fromTop: hiddenFrameHeight)
             }
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.