# How to hide the cells under the table view section header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a plain table view , the table view section header's background color is clear , is there any way to hide the cells under the section while scrolling ? 
Please see the image below :

[image]

Here is the `viewForHeaderInSection` implementation :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SYReminderHeaderCell")
    let header = cell as! SYReminderHeaderCell
    header.headerTitleLabel.textColor = .white
    header.configureSectionItems()
    guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else {
        return nil
    }
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    let title =  SYDateUtils.prepareSectionTitleForTimeLineView(stringDate: sectionInfo.name)
    header.setHeaderTitleAttribute(title: title)
    let subTitle = SYDateUtils.prepareSectionSubTitleForTimeLineView(stringDate: sectionInfo.name)
    header.setSubHeaderTitleAttribute(subTitle: subTitle)
    header.separaterHeaderHeightConstraint.constant = 1/UIScreen.main.scale
    header.separaterHeader.alpha = 0.0
    header.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want your headerview to stick at the top use another view above the tableview.

Comment: I want to hide the cell under the section while scrolling . Thank you

Comment: Why dont you use a view above tableview?

Comment: What do you mean by use a view above table view , view will hide the section !

Comment: I found a work around solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127138/how-to-mask-uitableviewcells-underneath-a-uitableview-transparent-header/24800307